# не выводит содержимое list

Tags: c++, std-list

Есть вот такой класс. Когда в `main` пытаюсь вывести содержимое `list`, выкидывает ошибка:

> "list iterators incompatible".

Ошибка именно в этих строках:

```
for (list <string>::iterator k = a[i].getsIngridients().begin(); k != a[i].getsIngridients().end(); k++) {
            cout << *k << endl;
        }
```

**dish.h**

```
 class dish {
private:
    string sDishName;
    list <string> sIngridients;
    double dPrice;
    double dPrepareTime;
public:
    DISHDLL_API dish();
    DISHDLL_API dish(string name, list<string> ingr, double price, double time);
    DISHDLL_API ~dish();
    DISHDLL_API void addDish(dish &newDish, vector <dish> &allDishes);
    DISHDLL_API void delDish(int index, vector <dish> &allDishes);
    //get funcs
    DISHDLL_API string getsDishName();
    DISHDLL_API list<string> getsIngridients();
    DISHDLL_API double getdPrice();
    DISHDLL_API double getdPrepareTime();
};
```

**dish.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Dish.h"

dish::dish() {

}

dish::dish(string name, list<string> ingr, double price, double time) {
    sDishName = name;
    sIngridients = ingr;
    dPrice = price;
    dPrepareTime = time;
}

dish::~dish() {

}

void dish::addDish(dish &newDish, vector<dish> &allDishes) {
    allDishes.push_back(newDish);
}

void dish::delDish(int index, vector<dish> &allDishes) {
    allDishes.erase(allDishes.begin() + index);
}


string dish::getsDishName() {
    return sDishName;
}

list<string> dish::getsIngridients() {
    return sIngridients;
}

double dish::getdPrice() {
    return dPrice;
}

double dish::getdPrepareTime() {
    return dPrepareTime;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Dish.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    vector<dish> a;
    string str = "name";
    list<string> list1;
    list1.push_back(str);
    list1.push_back(str);
    double price = 5.1;
    double time = 10.5;

    dish b(str, list1, price, time);

    b.addDish(b, a);
    b.addDish(b, a);
    b.addDish(b, a);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        cout << a[i].getsDishName() << endl;
        cout << a[i].getdPrice() << endl;
        cout << a[i].getdPrepareTime() << endl;
        cout << "INGRIDIENTS" << endl;
        for (list <string>::iterator k = a[i].getsIngridients().begin(); k != a[i].getsIngridients().end(); k++) {
            cout << *k << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта функция

```
DISHDLL_API list<string> getsIngridients();
```

каждый раз возвращает временную копию списка. Поэтому итераторы, получаемые каждый раз для этих временных объектов не совместимы между собой, так как они принадлежат разным спискам.

Измените объявление функции следующим образом

```
DISHDLL_API list<string> & getsIngridients();
                        ^^^
```

Comment: Появились такие вот ошибки, после изменения   ![Ошибки](https://pp.vk.me/c628021/v628021910/2ac3b/IXWFzYLt29M.jpg).

Comment: @smallup Задайте новый вопрос относительно ваших новых ошибок. Я не знаю. как вы там меняли свой код. Это может продолжаться бесконечно: вы будете менять сой код, и у вас будут появляться новые ошибки.